# Continue to show angular default loading until angular2 router is resolved?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Angular2 cli provide default loading until it get bootstrapped `<app-root>Loading...</app-root>`. 
Then angular2 route resolver initiate API call to check weather user is authenticated or not after that it goes to desired route.

But in between this process I can see blank screen.
Actually angular default **Loading...** is removed and resolver is taking some time to get resolved.

So is there anyway to continue showing angular default loading symbol until router is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below,

In your app-root component,

```
showSpinner = false;

constructor(private router: Router) {}

ngOnInit(){
   this.router.events
      .filter(e => {
        return (e instanceof NavigationStart)
          || (e instanceof NavigationEnd ||
            e instanceof NavigationCancel ||
            e instanceof NavigationError);
      })
      .map(e => (e instanceof NavigationStart))
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .subscribe(showSpinner => {
        this.showSpinner = showSpinner;
      });
}
```

In HTML, use `showSpinner` property to show some gif or animation, you may also use (not tested but should work) to show the `Loading...` message or what ever content you had initially,

```
<ng-content *ngIf="showSpinner" ></ng-content>
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks Madhu,, but its is not working ..Angular 2 does not compile/process bindings in index.html.. So I am not getting my "Loading..." in ng-content

Comment: Hmm.. you may have loading text in your app-root component with a ngif with show spinner.., did you try that? cheers!!

Comment: Yup, I tried but not working .. loading text is in my index.html not in app-root component...

Comment: Did you try putting loading text in app root component as well?